# How to do Database validation in Async function Nodejs(Express) API

Tags: node.js, express

I'm inserting user in SQl SERVER with the following code which is working fine for insertion purpose and I want to validate user that it already exist in database or not before inserting it, my function looks like:

```
async function addUser(user) {
    try {
      let pool = await sql.connect(config);
      let addUser = await pool.request()
      .input('userName', sql.NVarChar, user.userName)
      .input('email', sql.NVarChar, user.email)
      .input('password', sql.NVarChar, user.password)
        
      .query(`insert into testRegistration01 (userName, password, email) 
      values(@userName, @password,@email)`);
      
        UserAdd=addUser.recordsets;
      console.log(UserAdd,{message:"Record inserted"})
    }
    catch (err) { 
      console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You can mark any or combination of columns as unique so that the database would prevent inserting whenever the record already exists.

Comment: But how i send error in response

Comment: SQL allows you to define constraints on columns and tables. Constraints give you as much control over the data in your tables as you wish. If a user attempts to store data in a column that would violate a constraint, an error is raised. This applies even if the value came from the default value definition.

more: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-UNIQUE-CONSTRAINTS